# Is it possible to refund or cancel a contract based wallet transaction?

Tags: transactions, gas-refund

Is it possible to refund/cancel transactions? I have sent Ether to a merchant and the funds are away from my wallet, but the merchant said I used a wrong wallet... (I sent from my contract wallet adress and they say, that they are not supporting funds from contract wallets...) What can I do know? I can see, that they received my funds, but they don´t want to give it to me. Is it possible to make a transaction donation, to get my money back?

Answer (score 4):

> "the merchant said I used a wrong wallet"

- If you meant wrong deposit address instead of wrong wallet then if the transaction is confirmed you Ether is gone and there is probably nothing you can do.

> "What can I do know? I can see, that they received my funds, but they
>   don´t want to give it to me."

- If you can prove that the merchant gave you the wrong address, then submit that evidence to them and request a refund. I assume by "I can see that they received my funds" that you mean the transaction was confirmed on the blockchain.

> "Is it possible to make a transaction donation, to get my money back?"

- I have no idea what you mean by this