# Sent to PRIVATE address in etherwallet instead of ACCOUNT address

Tags: myetherwallet

I have sent ether to my PRIVATE ADDRESS instead of ACCOUNT ADDRESS in myetherwallet - What do I do? Please HELP!!!

Comment: There's no such thing as private address in Ethereum. Did you send it to your private keys? Also this may be relevant https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers, if a transaction already has been confirmed on the blockchain it is unlikely it will reversed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ethreum sent to my wrong adress im worried it wont be recovered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32343/ethreum-sent-to-my-wrong-adress-im-worried-it-wont-be-recovered)

Comment: A sidenote: Remove all your monney from your address.
You compromised it by sending to the private key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "private key" when you say "private address" and the transaction went through, then I'm sorry to say that your ether is unrecoverable.

The only way to recover the ether would be to know the private key for the address it was sent to. Unfortunately, the address it was sent to was roughly random (probably the first 20 bytes of your private key), so finding its private key would be as difficult as breaking into any other account.

Because that private key was partially exposed, it would also be prudent to move any other ether out of the address you were trying to send to. (I'm not sure by how much, but exposing part of the private key for an address weakens the security of that address.)

Comment: When I opened myetherwallet I was instructed to copy both a 'private address' AND a 'private key'.

Comment: I used that address by mistake - can I still access the ether somewhere? Thankyou

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what you mean by "private address." I just created a wallet on MyEtherWallet.com and saw no mention of that term.

Comment: I just double checked saved files and they are one and the same, just under different labels - however I transfered ether from coinspot over 60 minutes ago and it isnt in 'myetherwallet' yet - is it normal for it to take so long?

Comment: It's atypical for a transaction to take that long. Did Coinspot give you a transaction hash or the address they're sending from? If so, you can look for the transaction on etherscan.io to find out what's happening.