# Can I "cancel" a token transfer transaction by sending ether?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, myetherwallet

The OMG transaction is listed [here on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8aa368afd0f87418888e0614fb1a497e6780ca45d9e92f7f10c0142096490959). I initiated it around 7:30 AM this morning, even though the timestamp on that page always seems to restart everytime I refresh the page. I found a [myetherwallet.com help page](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html) for cancelling a pending transaction. The instructions for cancelling a transaction involve generating a '0 **ETH**' transaction to your own address, along with other details. My question is, should I still be doing a 0 ETH transaction to myself, or a 0 OMG transaction to myself since the original transaction was OMG and not ETH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 0 ETH transaction with the same nonce as the transaction to be cancelled is fine. The same account cannot have two transactions with the same nonce; any transaction (with high enough gas price), really, could be used to replace the one that's still pending.

Comment: That just confused me further. The original transaction was for OMG. According to the instructions, it is implying the cancelling transaction should consist of ETH. Should it be ETH, or OMG?

Comment: Every time you use your account for anything (interacting with a contract, sending eth), you create a transaction on the blockchain. These transactions are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, etc -- this is the nonce. Every transaction number must be unique and be exactly one greater than the transaction that preceded it for each account. The transaction you wish to cancel has a nonce of 0. If you send a *different* transaction with nonce of 0, whichever is mined first is the one that becomes permanent in the blockchain. It doesn't matter what that transaction contains.

Comment: To increase the likelihood that the replacement transaction becomes a permanent fixture of the blockchain instead of the original transaction, you need to set a higher gas price to increase the chances of it being mined first.

Comment: I see you've been successful :)