# I accidentally sent the same transaction twice because it was pending

Tags: transactions, wallets, addresses, pending-transactions, recovery

I seem to have gotten myself in a bit of a pickle. I sent some ether to another one of my wallets. The gas price was too low and it was pending for hours.

I read online that if you send the same transaction (to the same wallet and everything) with a higher gas price, the transaction with the higher gas price will override the previous one and you are good to go. I did this and the transaction is stuck on pending.

When I take a look at the Etherscan page, usually it just shows the first transaction. But, sometimes when I refresh, it occasionally shows both transactions as pending. I'm a little spooked and don't know what to do.

Any information/advice/guidance would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Every once in a while, I a message from my wallet pops up saying "java socket timeout exception".

Comment: The most important part here is that both transactions have the same nonce. If they do, only one will go through. See comments in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32569/can-i-cancel-a-token-transfer-transaction-by-sending-ether