# transaction failed - out of gas (How can i return my ethereum and cancel Transaction)

Tags: transactions, blockchain, gas, raw-transaction

[image]

How can i return my ether and cancel this transaction.??
and Ethereum will be return back fund Cryptopia right..?? 
Transaction link: 0x0991adfb4e316c920f32365b8949e46ae741c055547257e848c6fe92aa308757

thank you.

Comment: The transaction has already been mined and cannot be reversed. See this question for the details https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers.

For failed transactions the ether is returned immediately to the sender address. 

Your exchange appear to use a shared account, so they may not process the failed transactions automatically, you may have to contact their support for further options.