# sent my eth to unknown eth FREEWALLET address

Tags: ether

How can i recover my eth it was sent to an eth address with a one transaction from FREEWALLET. I am using the trust wallet while sending and im very sure that what i copay and paste is the same transaction from the previous one.

0x1b38d30857a869263545e62ce5d0333c79ac02ff330a3665bc66c93203d6c1c7 tx hash

thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot recover sent ETH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse or cancel a transaction or recover lost ethers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers)

Answer (score 0):

You only can recover the sended ether if you have private key of destination ethereum account.