# Uniswap transaction

Tags: transactions, uniswap

I swapped one coin for another on Uniswap and the transaction shows successful on etherscan but it ended up in the wrong wallet. Is there a way to get the crypto back? Thanks.

Comment: Show us the transaction hash. If you really did token swap then uniswap is sending the tokens which you want to the address which you initially used to sign the swap transaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse or cancel a transaction or recover lost ethers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers)