# Sent ETH to ETC address within Ledger Nano S. Confirmed on Etherscan, but not appearing in Wallet?

Tags: ledger-nano-s

Sent ETH to ETC within Ledger Nano S (send/recieve)

Tx Confirmed (Success) on Etherscan, but not showing up in Ledger.

Is there any way to recover?

Many thanks

Comment: And we're expected to answer that without any further details??? Where is a link to the transaction on Etherscan? What is your wallet address?

Comment: you may want to make sure that you are looking at the right chain - you may be looking at the ETH mainnet instead of ETC. If this is not the case, please provide more details: how did you send, and links to the confirmed txs. Thanks!

Comment: Hi both, many thanks for coming back to me.  Apologies i should have sent more detail in the first place.  txn hash: 0xc5a7675690b7a8413e060e132e613b484846261ea5dd08075fbb56aa8ece3da2. I did a simple Send: from my Nano wallet ( i believe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse or cancel a transaction or recover lost ethers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone looking at this in the future**, Ledger recently published an ETH Recovery app which makes it much easier to recover assets sent to the wrong address (e.g., ETH sent to ETC address, but also the other way around). There is a full usage guide available on [MyCrypto's knowledge base here](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/hardware-wallets/ledger/how-to-recover-assets-sent-to-the-wrong-address).

---

You should be able to access the coins if you change the derivation path to the ETC path. I don't think Ledger Live has an option to change the derivation path, but you can use MyCrypto to do that:

- Make sure you have the **ETH** app open on your Ledger device. Open MyCrypto in a browser, make sure you are on the **ETH** network.
- Select the Ledger option and click the button to connect.
- You should see a list of addresses, and the derivation path on top (by default it's "Ledger (ETH)"). First try changing the derivation path to "Ledger (ETC)" and see if your address shows up.
- If it doesn't, you have to manually set the "new" ETC derivation path, by selecting the "Custom" option, and entering `m/44'/61'/0'/0`. You should see your address as the first one in the list.
- If it still doesn't show up, try changing the `0'` to `1'`, `2'`, for example `m/44'/61'/1'/0`.

It's possible however that the "new" ETC derivation path does not work however, depending on the version of your Ledger device, since Ledger changed which derivation paths can be accessed a while ago. In that case you probably have to use your recovery phrase (seed) to access the address. I recommend that you do this **on an offline, airgapped computer** to prevent malware from accessing your recovery phrase. Alternatively, you can also reset your Ledger device to get a new recovery phrase after moving all funds to a temporary address, but that's slightly more work.

- Download MyCrypto's desktop application and (optionally) move it to an offline, airgapped computer.
- Select the mnemonic phrase option and enter your mnemonic phrase. Unless you use a passphrase, you can leave the passphrase field empty. Note that the PIN on the Ledger device is not your passphrase in this case.
- Click choose your address, and change the derivation path again in the same way as mentioned above. You may have to use the "new" ETC derivation path again.

From there you can sign and send a transactionas normal. If you're using an offline computer, you can follow [this guide for sending a transaction offline](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/how-to-make-an-offline-transaction).

Be *very* careful when entering your recovery phrase in an online computer. If it's ever exposed to malware, they have access to all funds on your Ledger device.

Comment: Hi Morten.  Many thanks for the Post. With your help, i was able to find the Coins on my Wallet.  There was a sublte difference though: 
I had to open the ETH Classic app on my Ledger device.
Then through MyCrypto (on the ETH network) I connected to the Ledger.
I selected a Custom derivation path and found it by entering m/44'/61'/0'/0 (first one in the list).

Comment: However, my one remaining issue is being able to send the coins (for example) back to the original ETH address.  I am now presented with a MyCrypto error TransportStatusError: Ledger device: Invalid data received (0x6a80). Check to make sure contract data is on.  But within the Ledger, it is "on".  is ther a final thing i am missing.  Grateful for your help.

Comment: I think this happens because you're trying to sign an ETH transaction with the ETC app open on your Ledger device. Like I mentioned, Ledger changed which derivation paths can be accessed, and trying to use the ETC derivation path with the ETH app open will likely result in an error.

Comment: Morton - I followed the above instructions and was sucessfully able to withdraw the ETH coins.  I appreciate your help & guidance.