# Transaction having low gasPrice makes all the other transactions pending state

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, pending-transactions

When transactions are on pending, is it possible to follow a path to fix this situation without deleting the transaction.rlp file and shutting down the machine?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean by "transaction.rpl file"? You will need to either cancel or "speed up" the first transaction to unblock the rest of your pending transactions. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Is it possible to do what you said without deleting the transaction.rlp file and shutting down the machine?

Comment: It is possible to replace an existing transaction but gas price has to increase by some percentage. Geth default is 10% but it is configurable by the node operator.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your help! Can u give me more information about replace an existing trancsaction and how can i chance for separately for each transaction?

Comment: @TanerBİLGİN Just create another transaction with the same nonce but with 10% increase in gas price. How are you creating your transactions?

Comment: @Ismael I create transactions automatically using web3.and I try to increase it by 10% as you say, I don't get any results.

Comment: @TanerBİLGİN Did you try increasing more than 10%? like 15% Can you ask the operator how much is needed? Is it a testnet or mainnet? How much gas price are you using?