# I tried to convert my Dexkit Tokens to Bep20, Transaction failed, but I lost my crypto?

Tags: transactions, tokens, metamask

This is the Hash: 0xb49d9f560980ec438a9ee6c370d4fff8261971c602338bc5d053d01006d71b34

Im not sure what I did, but I thought it cancelled. My Dexkit Tokens nevertheless are gone and don't show up in my Metamask. Anyone can explain this Operation to me? Im new to this kind of crypto trading stuff.
Thanks already for helping!

Comment: There's a previous transaction 0x6bc4fb9fe7f440c4d229eea61a340abc94a65ed8a5e0f3ecd9062e2ec71cdad3 that made the transfer, the other failed because the funds were already gone.

Comment: Ah, but what does this Transfer mean? The other one with the Hash: 0x6bc4fb9fe7f440c4d229eea61a340abc94a65ed8a5e0f3ecd9062e2ec71cdad3

Comment: and where did my crypto went, and can I get it back?

Comment: Both transactions are equal. It appears that instead of canceling the first one you send the same transaction again. Unless you have the recipient 0x533e3c0e6b48010873B947bddC4721b1bDFF9648 private key there's nothing you can do to recover those tokens, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers.

Comment: I used a BSC Token Converter called "Anyswap". Now it shows up. The thing is that there are Transfers In and out from. Im not sure what this is, I just thought I could transfer my dexkit from ETH to BSC Network.

Comment: anyone? would awesome if id not just throw away my tokens. :(

Comment: Did you try contacting their social accounts? They seem to have a twitter account `AnyswapNetwork`.