# I sent my ETH to my address 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a. However when I open it in my metamask I can't see this account

Tags: metamask, etherscan, addresses

Basically I sent my ETH to my address 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a(Metamask). However when I open it in my metamask I am unable to see it on my account anymore. I humbly ask if how can I go on that account using my metamask 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a ? Or can I still recover it? I have a recover seed phrase on this account. But I can't still see it on my end. I already tried to create account just thinking if the account is there. But still cant see it. Please help me!! Please.

Comment: Looking at that address in etherscan it shows it received a transfer from a contract at block 12845801. Metamask doesn't show "internal transaction" from a contract but it should reflect the balance. If you want to check if the seed phrase generate that address you can use another wallet like MyEtherWallet or MyCrypto.

Comment: HI thanks for the response. I just checked my seed phrase just today but the account is still not there. I humbly ask if can I still transfer it to my other wallet using the transaction hash? If ever I am unable to access that wallet on my metamask anymore? Please help.

Comment: Once a transaction appears confirmed on the blockchain it is unlikely to be canceled or reverted (see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers). If you have the private key or seed phrase for 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a you should be able to transfer them from that address.

Comment: Oh. Unfortunately I cant do anything on this. So the fund will just stay on that address? By the way I believe that the address still belongs to me as I have saved it here. I just dont understand why the system provides me that address. Maybe any help if I contact etherscan support?

Comment: It is unlikely that etherscan could do anything they do not provide wallet services. How did you create that address? With Metamask you can create multiple addresses from the same seed, perhaps you created several. Use "+ Create Account" to add more accounts.

Comment: I tried it already but still the same cant see the account. I only have 1 seed phrase on my account. How about metamask sir can they also help me?

Comment: You can ask them, but without the private key or the seed phrase that produces the address 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a there's nothing that can be done.

Comment: I really appreciate your response sir. How can I see that wallet sir belongs to me or anybody because the system itself provided me that address.

Comment: I also believe that since that is my account. Meaning to say that ETH will be stuck there and anyone cant retrieve that?

Comment: There's no registry with account's ownership. If you have the private key that generates the address then you are the owner. The funds will be there until someone with the private key create a transaction, no one can recover the funds without the private key.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response sir. Oh no I don't know what to do right now. Its a big amount :( . I am also curious why my computer keeps on generating this wallet 0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a  even though I copied other wallet address. Sir is there anything that I can do for this? :( Wish me luck

Comment: I won't use that computer for Ethereum related things, it is likely it has a malware. Before continuing using blockchain probably you have to learn a bit more how to protect yourself, how to use wallets.