# Unauthorized Transaction

Tags: transactions

Hi I hope you’re safe & sound.

I want to report an unauthorize transaction. Basically I sent ETH to my Ronin wallet address

“ ronin:0788fbfe21bbe3b7d33d1828a0f89773cd774031
” 4 days ago which is successful, base on the etherscan transaction. I checked my ronin wallet under activities to check if my ETH is there it states that it was successful. However, after an hour my ETH under my Ronin wallet just got transferred without my permission to an unknown address which is not seen in the activities under my ronin wallet and view explorer tab.

My Metamask wallet: 0xf9A9d3025ab51C35209E8f848E7178395f1EcD9a

My Ronin wallet: ronin:0788fbfe21bbe3b7d33d1828a0f89773cd774031

Unknown Address: 0xf30431d4e31e6e54d9338eb8f54da5eceadc4cb4

On the other hand, here is the official receipt of the metamask EtherScan that it was successfully transferred to my Ronin wallet address:

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

The etherscan states that it was successful.

However, below is the unknown transaction which is not seen under my activities in my Ronin wallet and view in Explorer tab. Please see screenshot below:

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

Transaction Hash: 0x6a05e85436630bb23548398cbc9a030e82a4bafb2ab21922d91f5dfaf889bf09

The last screenshot states that, from my Ronin Wallet sending to Unknown address (0xf30431d4e31e6e54d9338eb8f54da5eceadc4cb4)

which is totally not visible under my activities on my Ronin Wallet address and view in Explorer tab.

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

Please settle this case as soon as possible. Or if it’s okay to talk to you on phone maybe I can ask for your contact number for this to be clearly explained.

Comment: I suggest to not include personal information in the question. Did you try contacting the ronin wallet customer support? In any case there's not much you can do. Transaction once mined in the Ethereum blockchain are unlikely to be reversed read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers.

Comment: your computer has been compromised and probably you have a backdoor. I suggest getting very old computer and do crypto trading only on that computer. Otherwise you are going to be hacked periodically