# Why did the dropped and replaced transaction go to a different address?

Tags: transactions, dai

I tried to transfer some DAI from my instar wallet to my CoinBase wallet.  The initial transaction was 'dropped and replaced' and the replacement transaction was successful, but appears the funds were sent to a different wallet.

The first transaction is at: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd7264f8abbc308d0b9736f702cf0c074916a4565ed72682a6b33c76c3e9f6e7b

My DAI wallet address at CoinBase is 0x0b5Cb7d7f5EA4B1c7319f2486B728D120B629d55 which is the value that shows in the Token Transfer To field.

That transaction was replaced with https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3e47a07cde5ad14abb8ac9cba1b82edb6816ad5ea3f209888622bc6e24a996e0 which has the same From address as the first transaction, but now has a different To address.

Can anybody explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Look at the 'Input Data' detail in the transaction both have different parameters, for example the dropped is for 32 dai and the second is for 35 dai. So either you made two different transactions and the second override the first, or vthe wallet has a serious problem.

Comment: I'm relatively new to this myself, but I found the 32 DAI value strange because it was supposed to be 35 DAI as shown in the second.  I only initiated one transaction myself.  I've attempted to report the problem to Instar (the source) but haven't gotten any response from them.  Not sure what, if anything can be done at this point.  I was hoping that I could learn what had happened so that I could avoid it in the future if it was a mistake that I had made.  For now I'm glad it wasn't anymore than 35 DAI that was lost...

Comment: Only the recipient of the 35 dai could return them, see this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/25866 for the technical details. Now there are many wallets available in mobile, desktop, try several and decide which one fits better with your usage. Many wallets support seed phrases of 12 or 24 words that are compatible and you could switch between them.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the 35 DAI were lost at this point.  Whoever received them, I guess it was their lucky day and not mine.  I still don't have an understanding of what caused the address to change.  I only initiated the one request and provided the correct wallet address (I copied it directly from the coinbase site (for my DAI wallet) and have confirmed it was correct).  How is it possible that it changed on the replacement transaction?

Comment: In theory a wallet should ask for confirmation when sending or replacing a transaction. It is a strange case if the wallet was hacked then it would have moved all your funds. I'm inclined to think the wallet didn't show properly the operation and you accepted without noticing the change. Check for malware, there are some that can modify the clipboard when you paste an address.