# Speeding up transaction failed, and I may have locked my account up

Tags: opensea

I completed a sale on OpenSea and initially set the gas fee too low. I attempted to speed up the Atomic Match transaction, however I received a 'Transaction Failed' message and now am unable to speed it up again.

The transaction had been pending for over 3 hours and so I attempted to cancel it. This was unsuccessful through MetaMask's interface.

I then attempted to send a new transaction with the same nonce, which also received an error.

My last attempt was to reset my MetaMask account, which removed the transaction queue, then try and send a duplaicte nonce transaction once again. This sent the transaction, with a higher gas fee, but now both transactions are showing as pending on etherscan and I cannot get either to complete.

Do I have any way to resolve this?

Comment: What's the transaction hash? If the transaction was mined the it is no longer feasible to replace it, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this transaction to "go away", you have two options:

1. Just keep waiting until this pending transaction is potentially purged from the mempool.
2. Send a transaction with the same nonce as your pending transaction from **yourself** to **yourself** sending a total of 0 ETH, but paying a high gas to ensure the tx is included in the next block.

DeFi Dad has a great tutorial video on how to do this type of transaction using Metamask:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EcJNCapRq8