# How to recover funds mistakenly sent to Polygon instead of ETH Gnosis Safe (1.1.1)

Tags: gnosis-safe

I currently have an Ethereum Mainnet Gnosis Safe (1.1.1). I am looking for help to see if it is possible to use the CLI to re-create the same Gnosis Safe on Polygon to recover funds sent there by mistake.

I tried the following tutorial but it only works for safe version 1.3+:
https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741

Can someone direct me to a guide or provide instructions on how to do this? Ideal end result: I can successfully deploy a Gnosis Safe on Polygon with the same address, so that I can go in through the Gnosis webapp (using an owner wallet) and access the funds that were previously sent to this address in error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse or cancel a transaction or recover lost ethers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers)

Comment: if your safe was deployed with `createProxyWithNonce` (look that up in transaction data of Safe creation tx), the tutorial will also work.

Answer (score 2):

The Safe team provides a guide on this: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

As @mikheevm mentioned it depends how your Safe was created. I would recommend following the help center article and reaching out to the Safe team on their [discord](https://chat.gnosis-safe.io) if you require further help, as this depends on your specific setup.