# What has happened to these ETH swaps in Trust Wallet?

Tags: etherscan, swaps, trustwallet

A friend of mine was trying to swap USDT to ETH in Trust Wallet. First he swapped 150 USDT, which was subtracted from his USDT balance, but no ETH was added. Second time, we tried to swap only 1 USDT to ETH for test, to see if we could figure out what's happening, and suddenly about 0.03 ETH was subtracted!

Please kindly have a look at the latest transactions on [this address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1c632ff286a9751ed1f3cafad8eefe52904b0498). I want to know what has happened to his coins, burnt irreversibly, or is there some way to get it back?

Comment: Just corrected the wallet address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction on March 5th https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9318b7d4abb0ee9be9e23b7aa46b6591a933ccc4421e5863f02721fac6086768

The address has received an internal transaction `0.043121488261291545` ethers.

> Transfer
> 0.043121488261291545 ETH From 0xa7Ca2C86...C2b0Db22A To 0x1C632FF2...2904b0498

The problem was that the transaction fees were too high `0.043580632330493482` ether.

---

Similarly the transaction on March 8th https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f3e8e48856bb78cb6136ca6d54c652a4c642cd9d5ef3e19d25765aa93bf6da0 paid `0.029879213132278016` on transaction fees.

---

Before making another swap either wait until the gas prices are lower, or look for a better swap alternative.

Comment: Thank you. I got confused, By "Either wait until the gas prices are lower, or look for a better alternative", you mean for the future transactions? And these two are already done and gone?

Comment: @asmani Transaction on the blockchain are final and cannot be undone (s ee https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers for the technicalities). The comment was an advice before making another swap.

Comment: That's, sad. He didn't receive any warnings or notice beforehand. 170$ fee is insane. Btw I check gas fee calculators and at 185 gwei the fee would be around 15$?

Comment: I think metmask shows the cost before the user approval. The transaction fee varies depending on the network usage, and contracts involved. Ethereum mainnet is quite expensive for tokens swaps, see average costs of some operations https://etherscan.io/gastracker. Ether and token transfers are that expensive (under $15 as of 2024-03-14), but token swaps are quite high ($60-70). For small amounts it is not convenient.